# Embed Web Page in an App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've created a simple Windows Phone app that launches the Google+ Mobile site. What I'd like to do, though, is a bit more complicated than that, and I have absolutely no idea how do to it.

Basically, I need help with this:

1. Embed mobile Google+ in an app.
2. If a user clicks on a link that's not on the same domain, open that link in IE
3. Have an application bar with "back" and "home" buttons. Back could work with the built in back button if that'd be better.

If someone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great. If someone wants to help me with this project, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using a `WebBrowser` control.
2. You can create a handler for the `Navigating` event for the `WebBrowser` to check for the domain. Something like this:

`<phone:WebBrowser Navigating="OnNavigating"/>`

```
private void OnBrowserPostNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //check for domain here, open IE accordingly
}
```

1. You can latch onto the hardware back button and use that for your navigation similar to the way IE does on the phone. If you search SO there are plenty of questions regarding that. For the Home button, simply use the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>` xaml element and add a button with a handler to do the navigation for you.

Comment: Thanks, this almost helps. If I can figure it out from here I'll be sure to  come back and mark as answered. Thing is, I'm very very new to this, this is literally my first windows phone/c# project. I'm mostly a web designer so this is still confusing to me.

Comment: I can't seem to make this embed the page. It just opens up IE like my original thing. What I would like is for it to embed the page inside of the app.